# Google maps api v3 quota graph

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, quota

we are using google maps api v3 in our web application, but it started to display message about exceeding daily quota. But I looked in developers console and I cannot find any message about this, or any graph. When I take a look on numbers for maps api we have around 5000 every day. Is there any way how I can get to quota which we exceed? Some more info? Are there any other quotas?

Thank you

Comment: *When I take a look on numbers for maps api we have around 5000 every day* ...where did you see the 5000?

Comment: In the developer console, open your project, hit *APIs* under *APIs & auth* on the left hand side, and you should see a quota column on the right.

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is a graph you can see if you're going to the [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Under this link all your projects are listed, when you're logged in. Select the project you want and you'll see a graph with requests on the used APIs by this project with possible billing an more informations.

**EDIT**

Also Google observes the `google-api` tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api), add this tag to your Question and maybe you'll get official help.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I have managed to fix the maps. I have found bug which caused every few seconds refresh of maps. But I havent reached 25000 limit. All the graphs mentioned above I saw and nothing there. I have found that there is also some other quota. It is pitty that message doesnt say which I have reached. Even If I would like to buy higher quota I wouldnt know which one.